# Uploading file from Google Drive to Google Cloud Storage in chunks using Content-Range

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api, google-cloud-storage

so as the title says, I'm trying to import files from Google Drive to Google Cloud Storage. You'd imagine this to be pretty frictionless as these are two wholly Google-managed services, right?

Well not so in my experience. I am fetching the files from Drive in chunks using the `"googleapis"` NodeJS package and Range header:

```
    drive.files.get(
      { fileId: file.id, alt: "media" },
      {
        responseType: "arraybuffer",
        headers: {
          Range: `bytes=${range[0]}-${range[1]}`,
        },
      },
    ),
```

First of, `drive.files.get` requests (and other) hang at times and the timeout parameter doesn't help (and why I omitted it in the example). I have to manually add a timeout around each Gaxios request to properly quit the forever pending requests. Okay. Second, it seems Drive doesn't respect the provided Range headers and returns whatever chunk size it pleases. Huh. Well, I can work around that.

But the real problem starts when I want to upload this same chunk from Drive to Google Cloud Storage. For each chunk returned from Google Drive, I fire off requests using axios like so:

```
    let contentRangeStart = 0;

    const res = await axios.put(resumableUpload.url, buffer, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
        "Content-Length": buffer.byteLength,
        "Content-Range": `bytes ${contentRangeStart}-${contentRangeStart + buffer.byteLength - 1}/${file.size}`
      },
      validateStatus: (status: number) => [200, 201, 308].includes(status),
    })
```

Which works for the first chunk but then unexpectedly is left pending for the subsequent. I have no idea why the same file fetched from Drive is somehow altered so that it becomes unparsable by the GCS. You'd think I'm just passing content from one Bucket to another but it is inconceivable the passed Ranges & Content-Ranges don't match!

To add more to this madness, I got this work by parsing the returned `range: bytes=x` header and using that as the next offset. However, that byte range is different from the one I received from the Drive (if I upload 5242881 sized slice, it returns 5242879) and moreover, I end up with 1 byte smaller file (using two chunks) than my original! Wtf.

If someone could provide an explanation for all of this, I'd be immensely grateful. I just wonder if I am doing something wrong or is this supposed to be so difficult...

EDIT: Oh also, in some example it was recommended to use http2 protocol for importing from Drive that but just messed up the ranges even worse. Took a while to figure that bug out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay well, didn't think I'd find the answer so quickly but alas, I figured it out. I want to publicly reprimand whoever designed the flow for Google Cloud Storage chunked upload since the key to understanding it was this snippet: "The chunk size should be a multiple of 256 KiB (256 x 1024 bytes)." (The error message of `'Invalid request.  According to the Content-Range header, the upload offset is 5242881 byte(s), which exceeds already uploaded size of 5242880 byte(s).'` wasn't necessarily as helpful)

Should? SHOULD???? For the love of God, don't use such ambiguous language. It HAS TO BE a multiple of 256 KiBs. So what happened was, I fetched a 5 MB chunk from Drive which in fact was 5 MB + 1 byte long since I didn't realize the Range header has a similar inclusive range as Content-Range. Okay. But the huge time sink and waste of of my life and sanity was the fact GCS accepted the request of 5 MBs + 1 bytes (with Content-Length 5242881) but in fact only inserted the first 5242880 bytes! WTF. Sure, it returned in its response headers `range: bytes=0-5242879` but how was I supposed to figure out I'd have to reupload the last byte?

**It does not make sense**. If there's someone out there who might have the power to submit a ticket, please make it so it returns either a data object with eg message: "First 5242879 bytes uploaded, 1 discarded" or just plain old 400. This was extremely annoying and I wonder if S3 has just as pointless logic for chunked uploading.